# Retrieve info from table

Tags: sql

I need to retrieve the info of the employees that earn more money than the average wage of their department... we have departments named 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, ... and so goes on. Here I have managed to retrieve what I need for only one department. (40) How can I do it for as many departments as there may be?

This is my Query:

```
SELECT  * FROM    EMPLOYEE where (Department_ID='40')and 
 (
 employee_salary > 
  (select avg(employee_salary) from EMPLOYEE  where  Department_ID='40')   
 )
```

`Datatable`:
[image: data table]

Comment: Provide with your table structure first.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqoatxyglgllapr/Untitled.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this will do,

```
    SELECT  emp.* FROM    EMPLOYEE emp where emp.employee_salary >
      (  select avg(employee_salary) from EMPLOYEE new1 
         where emp.Department_ID=new1.Department_ID 
         group by  Department_ID  
      )
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! So you created 2 tables to make the comparison? Am i right?

Comment: @user1915345 He did not create 2 tables. He is using the same table, with with different aliases. So the table is just comparing with itself actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

```
select * from EMPLOYEE as e1
where e1.employee_salary > (select avg(employee_salary) 
                         from EMPLOYEE as e2 
                         where e1.department_id=e2.department_id
                         group by Department_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
    SELECT  *, avg(employee_salary) as average_salary 
FROM    EMPLOYEE 
where Department_ID='40' 
having average_salary<employee_salary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.* from employee as e inner join
    (select department_id, avg(employee_salary) as avg_salary
        from employee group by department_id) as f
on e.department_id = f.department_id
where e.employee_salary > f.avg_salary;
```